# Pass a generic type 'class' when only having a string

Tags: c#, reflection

In C# I have a method

```
public string GetString<T>() where T : class
```

In the calling function I have only the name of the class which I want to pass to `GetString()<T>`. E.g. "MyClass". How can I convert "MyClass" to `class`?
I tried it using `Type`s but I couldn't find a conversion.

EDIT:
The real example is from a database access class.
The client asks for information for a specific hardware component. This component is specified by a string. Based on this string I want to access a table with a known name pattern. Not hard coding table names allows us to add/remove tables from the database without the need to change the C# code.

The function which returns the needed information exists already and needs a `class` as generic type.

E.g.

```
string tblName = "HW_" + hwComponentFromClient;
string retValue = GetString<GetClassByString(tblName)>();
```

I need something like a method:

```
class GetClassByString(string);
```

Comment: Why do you have a string of your class? That seems to be the real issue. Why is it impossible to know at compile-time which class you want to use?

Comment: If you don't know the class at compile time you are going do have to resort to reflection or dynamic, neither of which are compile-time type safe.  Is there not a base class or interface that you can cast to?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the classname but you need to get it from the right assembly and pass the full name of the class (assembly name + class name, in my case `"TestAlexander.Test"`).

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
     Type classType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("TestAlexander.Test");
     Test test = new Test();
     typeof(Test).GetMethod("TestMethod").MakeGenericMethod(classType).Invoke(test, null);
     Console.Read();
   }
}
public class Test
{
    public void TestMethod<T>() where T: class
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Great success!");
    }
}
```

Comment: The `instance` is not necessarily related to `classType` like in your case. So it is likely that he has "instance" already (maybe it is `this`), and I do not think the asker will need `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't need to invoke a method though. I need the generic type 'class' only from knowing the class name. See also my edit.

Comment: @telandor Then the first line should do it, that gets the class. Going to edit

Comment: The question asks about calling `public string GetString<T>() where T : class` when the type `T` is only known as the type name. This answer is in the right ballpark, but doesn't specifically answer the question.

Comment: @Enigmativity Edited it.

Comment: I'll look at it into detail next week. But first tests showed that it does what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I would prefer: `class Program
{
   public void TestMethod<T>() where T: class
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Great success!");
   }

   static void Main()
   {
     Type classType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("RandomTestShit.Test");
     Program program = new Program();
     typeof(Program).GetMethod("TestMethod").MakeGenericMethod(classType).Invoke(program, null);
     Console.Read();
   }
}
public class Test
{
}` I.e. having the type whose string representation we have, not contain the generic method in question.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Both are kind of the same in my opinion, OP might have an object from another class that contains the method. The important parts from the question stay the same. (So far trying to edit out my "randomshittest" assembly :-( )